# Как создать два layout на одном экране?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Один для `canvas`, второй для `Button`. И работать с ними одновременно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В Delphi подойдёт?

Comment: Нет, не подойдёт. Только AS.

Comment: @sapeg, AS это `ActionScript`?

Comment: Ок. Только для Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не надо создавать два layout. Нужно создать отдельный класс, который наследуется от View или SurfaseView, и передать объект этого класса в разметку.

MyDraw.java

```
package com.example;

// импорты

public class MyDraw extends View{

private Paint paint = new Paint();

    public MyDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }  

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // Здесь рисуем, что надо.
    }
}
```

Дальше нужно этот View поместить в нужный layout. В нём также размещаем кнопку.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<com.example.MyDraw
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Вместо com.example.MyDraw нужно прописать существующий путь к классу MyDraw.
Наконец, устанавливаем разметку и обработчик нажатия кнопки в MainActivity.java.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            // Обрабатываем нажатие кнопки.

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Можно также посмотреть этот [пример](http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-custom-view/).

Comment: В смысле класс MyDraw.java?
  Создал как есть. Но что-то не так. Пишет класс 'MyDraw' is never used.

Comment: MyDraw - это ваш кастомный View. Есть TextView, есть EditText, которые также наследуются от View, а вы создаёте MyDraw (можете назвать иначе). И делаете с ним то, что хотите. Т.е. рисуете в вашем случае. Пишет 'MyDraw' is never used, потому как негде не используется. Добавьте его в разметку и предупреждение должно убраться.

Comment: Сделал. В режиме Text (на второй картинке) всё отображается как надо. Осталось разобраться почему на смартфоне не запускается.

Comment: Вылетает? С какой ошибкой? Или не компилится? Там в конструкторе MyDraw два параметра, если что.

Comment: Отлично. С двумя попёрло))